# How to set a contact's job title in Dynamics Nav 2009 using webservices

Tags: web-services, dynamics-nav

There are two webservices, which I've tried to use

- page 5050 Contact Card
- page 5055 Name Details

First service handles contacts and it's possible to set contact's name. However, in RTC there is a assist button in the Name field, so it's possible to fill in additional fields for name, such as

- Salutation Code
- Job Title
- Initials
- First Name
- Middle Name
- Surname
- Language Code

All these fields are listed in page 5055 webservice, but I can't understand how should I add a new record and link it to existing contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I've found is to create a new page on basis of respective table and select all needed fields, in this case, Contact_No. Afterward this page can be published as webservice.

Cons of this solution, is that you need to create a new page, which requires dev license.